# decode/revert characters with shift in python

Tags: python, bit-shift, shift

I have a function. the input would be a word, and every time each character will be added to the shifted value of the result.

```
def magic2(b):
res = 0
    for c in b:
       res = (res << 8) + ord(c)
       print(res)
return res
```

Because it uses shifts, I will lose some data. I wanna to decode/reverse this with exact letters of the input word.

For example, if input would be "saman", the output is result "495555797358" and step by step would be:

```
115
29537
7561581
1935764833
495555797358
```

How can I get back to the input word just with these outputs?

Comment: What do you mean by "because it uses shifts, I will lose some data"? If your characters are all Latin-1, shifting each one by 8 bits won't lose any data. If they are, you will lose bits, but only because you're shifting by only 8 bits instead of 21 or 32.

Comment: Meanwhile, what have you tried to decode this? If you need a hint, what happens if you use `chr(n & 0xff)` and `n >> 8` in a loop, or `n, c = divmod(n, 256)` in a loop? That should get you close, but there's a bit of trickiness left for you to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider what you're doing: for each character, you shift left by 8 bits, and then add on another 8 bits.<sup>1</sup>

So, how do you undo that? Well, for each character, you grab the rightmost 8 bits, then shift everything else right by 8 bits. How do you know when you're done? When shifting right by 8 bits leaves you with 0, you must have just gotten the leftmost character. So:

```
def unmagic2(n):
    while n > 0:
        c = chr(n & 0xff) # 0xff is (1 << 8) - 1
        n = n >> 8
```

Now you just have to figure out what to do with each `c` to get your original string back. It's not *quite* as trivial as you might at first think, because we're getting the leftmost character last, not first. But you should be able to figure it out from here.

---

<sub>1. If you're using the full gamut of Unicode, this is of course lossy, because you're shifting left by 8 bits and then adding on another 21 bits, so there's no way to reverse that. But I'll assume you're using Latin-1 strings here, or `bytes`—or Python 2 `str`.</sub>